# How do I mock react-native-google-analytics-bridge when using jest for testing?

Tags: unit-testing, google-analytics, react-native, jestjs

I am testing a module using jest and that module calls a function that in turn calls GoogleAnalyticsTracker from react-native-google-analytics-bridge. I've tried everything I can think of (the documentation is a bit sparse) to mock this function, but I always get the real module not the mocked module. Can you see which step I am getting wrong or missing?

```
jest.mock('react-native-google-analytics-bridge');
import {GoogleAnalyticsTracker} from 'react-native-google-analytics-bridge';

describe('testing mocking', () => {
  it ('should return undefined when mocked', () => {
    let tracker2 = new GoogleAnalyticsTracker(null);
    expect(tracker2).toBe(undefined);
  })
})
```

... but it always manages to find the unmocked module...

```
Expected value to be (using ===):
      undefined
    Received:
      {"allowIDFA": [Function allowIDFA], "setAnonymizeIp": [Function setAnonymizeIp], "setAppName": [Function setAppName], "setAppVersion": [Function setAppVersion], "setSamplingRate": [Function setSamplingRate], "setTrackUncaughtExceptions": [Function setTrackUncaughtExceptions], "setUser": [Function setUser], "trackEvent": [Function trackEvent], "trackEventWithCustomDimensionValues": [Function trackEventWithCustomDimensionValues], "trackException": [Function trackException], "trackMultiProductsPurchaseEvent": [Function trackMultiProductsPurchaseEvent], "trackMultiProductsPurchaseEventWithCustomDimensionValues": [Function trackMultiProductsPurchaseEventWithCustomDimensionValues], "trackPurchaseEvent": [Function trackPurchaseEvent], "trackScreenView": [Function trackScreenView], "trackScreenViewWithCustomDimensionValues": [Function trackScreenViewWithCustomDimensionValues], "trackSocialInteraction": [Function trackSocialInteraction], "trackTiming": [Function trackTiming], "transformCustomDimensionsFieldsToIndexes": [Function transformCustomDimensionsFieldsToIndexes]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer... you really do need to get the real object from the module before you try to mock it!

```
import {GoogleAnalyticsTracker} from 'react-native-google-analytics-bridge';
jest.mock('react-native-google-analytics-bridge');
```

I can now create a tracker...

```
let tracker1 = new GoogleAnalyticsTracker('ABC-123');
```

...and pass it into the function I am trying to test.

Jest creates `tracker1.trackTiming` and I can find out what parameters were passed to it by using...

```
console.log('tracker1',tracker1.trackTiming.mock.calls);
```

Which in my case returns the parameters that will be written to GoogleAnalytics without actually polluting my analytics data with test data.

Comment: I am glad you found the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to the party, and Google Analytics for mobile won't be supported after 31st Oct 2019, but, this is a solution as well (using [Jest module mocks solution](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules))

Create a `__mocks__/react-native-google-analytics-bridge.js` file with the following content:

```
export const setAppVersion = jest.fn();
export const setUser = jest.fn();
export const trackScreenView = jest.fn();
export const trackEvent = jest.fn();

export const  GoogleAnalyticsTracker = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    setAppVersion,
    setUser,
    trackScreenView,
    trackEvent
  };
});
```

Feel free to add the methods that you need, this is just a subset. This alone will make tests that depend on the react-native-google-analytics-bridge not fail.

If you want to test calls, on your test file:

```
import { setAppVersion } from 'react-native-google-analytics-bridge';
...
expect(setAppVersion).toHaveBeenCalledWith('1.0.0');
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the mocked version as the imported one?

```
var GoogleAnalyticsTracker = jest.mock('react-native-google-analytics-bridge');
```

Comment: I made some progress using `var GoogleAnalyticsTracker = jest.fn();` and in this case GoogleAnalyticsTracker is a mocked function that does all those useful things like count how many times it is called etc., but I still can't mock from the module. The error when I try and assign `let tracker2 = new GoogleAnalyticsTracker('ABC-123');` is that GoogleAnalyticsTracker is not a function. What I really need is for the all the objects in the module to be mocked so that I can test that they are all being called correctly.

Comment: I'm testing a module that in turn calls a logging module. I create the mocked tracker as above then pass it into the function under test so that it can be used by the logging function. Of course, when the logging function tries to call `tracker.trackTiming('testcategory', 13000, {name: 'LoadList'});` it fails because I have not mocked the module  `react-native-google-analytics-bridge` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `genMockFromModule` method by Jest and add it to the mocks.

```
const mockAnalytics = jest.genMockFromModule('react-native-google-analytics-bridge');
module.exports = mockAnalytics;
```